# Вставить код СИ в android

Tags: android

Изучаю Android, использую только андроид студио. Обрабатываю (хоть это громко сказано) изображения. Почему то android очень тормозит когда обрабатываешь по пикселям картинку в BitMap. Видел в Андроид Студии есть возможность создавать С/С++ файлы source/.h , но как их подключить к Java коду? После создания файла на СИ, обращаюсь с ява к функции в СИ, но віводит ошибку. Как правильно подключать файлі Си в код ?

Comment: это слишком большой вопрос. Фактически вам нужно почитать документацию об `ndk`. https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html